# Recursion and the Return Keyword

Tags: java, recursion

I'm currently working my way through the Java tutorials and am currently on Recursions.

I have the following code which calculates the factorial of any number passed to the factorial method

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //E.g 4! = 4*3*2*1(factorial 4)
        System.out.println(factorial(4));

    }
    private static int factorial(int value){
        //System.out.println(value);
        if (value == 1){
            return 1;
        }
        return factorial(value - 1)*value;
    }
}
```

I have trouble understanding the part

```
if (value == 1){
    return 1;
}
return factorial(value - 1)*value;
```

My understanding is that the return keyword simply terminates the method, and/or returns a value of the same type declared by the method(i.e int,String, etc).

What happens when the  following line is run?

```
return factorial(value - 1)*value;
```

the function is returning the total of (value - 1) * value, which would give me

```
(3)*4 = 12
(2)*3 = 6
(1)*2 = 2
```

with each passing iteration.However, `System.out.println(factorial(4));` gives me a total of `24`. How is this number derived from the method? There are no variables to store the sum of the values, so where is the program storing them? Also, how do I get `24` from these values?

```
(3)*4
(2)*3
(1)*2
```

While I know that `24` is derived from `4*3*2*1`, I do not see how that can be calculated from the above.

Any explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You've misinterpreted

```
return factorial(value - 1)*value;
```

The values being multiplied are `factorial(value - 1)` and `value`.  In other words, you can rewrite it like this:

```
return (factorial(value - 1)) * value;
```

So when you pass 4, you get this:

```
factorial(3) * 4;
```

which is equivalent to

```
(factorial(2) * 3) * 4;
```

which is equivalent to

```
((factorial(1) * 2) * 3) * 4;
```

which is equivalent to

```
1 * 2 * 3 * 4;
```

The way this works, which you can see easily if you step through the code with a debugger, is as follows:

1. The first call to the function passes `4`.  The function evaluates the if, then calls itself, passing `3`.  (The state of the first function call is preserved on the stack, so when this call returns, we can resume where we left off, now that we have the result of the function call.  This "stack" abstraction is not actually necessary to understand recursion.)
2. The second function call evaluates the if and calls itself, passing `2`.
3. The third function call evaluates the if and calls itself, passing `1`.
4. The fourth function call evaluates the if and returns 1.
5. The third function call then resumes, multiplying the return value of the function that just returned (`1`) with the value of its argument (`2`), returning the result (`2`).
6. The second function call then resumes, multiplying the return value of the function that just returned (`2`) with the value of its argument (`3`), returning the result (`6`).
7. The first function call then resumes, multiplying the return value of the function that just returned (`6`) with the value of its argument (`4`), returning the result (`24`).

Some optimizing compilers will change recursive calls into loops, but it's not generally possible to change a recursive call to a fixed expression, like `1 * 2 * 3 * 4`, because at compile time you don't generally know how deep the recursion will be.

All of this will be abundantly clear if you modify your code as follows and then step through it with a debugger:

```
private static int factorial(int value){
    if (value == 1){
        return 1;
    }
    int recursiveResult = factorial(value - 1);
    return recursiveResult * value;
}
```

Note that with each recursive call, we have to store the state of a "suspended" method, waiting for the result of the call, on the stack.  For this reason, if a method calls itself recursively (or a chain of methods call themselves in mutual recursion), there is a possibility for the stack to become full.  This is known as a stack overflow.  It is usually caused by incorrect logic in a function causing a recursive loop:

```
int stackOverflow() { return stackOverflow(); }
```

It can also be caused by a function that doesn't logically loop, but calls itself too many times because of the data passed to it.  For example, recursive functions are useful when working with tree data structures; if the tree is too tall, it can cause a stackoverflow.  So will the following, with some arguments, but not with others:

```
void possibleStackOverflow(int arg) { if (arg == 0) return; possibleStackOverflow(arg - 1); }
```

If you call `possibleStackOverflow(10)` you're probably fine, but `possibleStackOverflow(-1)` will throw an exception.

Also, by VM implementation limitations, calling possibleStackOverflow(Integer.MAX_VALUE) will throw an StackOverflowException

Comment: Hi Phoog, thanks for answering. Am i right in saying that when i run factorial(4), the program simply keeps expanding/ running recursively like what you've written in your answer, till it reaches count 1, where it then evaluates everything in the bracket ( 1 * 2 * 3 )*4, giving the answer 24?

Comment: Not really.  What it does is that it uses the stack.  (The compiler can, in certain circumstances, replace multiple stack frames with a loop, but in this case it will not.)  I'll add a bit to my answer to explain.

Answer (score 1):

Your return clause is returning the result of factorial(value-1)*value each factorial(value-1) will be replaced by the result of the method call.

This means factorial(4) is:

(factorial(1) * (factorial(2 -1) * (factorial(3 -1) * factorial(4 - 1)))) * 4

This will be

(1 * (2 * 3)) * 4 that is 24

Comment: This isn't quite correct.  The expression `(factorial(1) * (factorial(2 -1) * (factorial(3 -1) * factorial(4 - 1)))) * 4` actually evaluates to 1 * 1 * 2 * 6 * 4, which is 48.

Answer (score 1):

```
return factorial(value - 1)*value;
```

Returns the **factorial** of `value - 1` times `value`.

It goes like this:

> factorial(4)
>
> =factorial(3) * 4
>
> = factorial(2) * 3 * 4
>
> = factorial(1) * 2 * 3 * 4
>
> = 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 = 24

Answer (score 1):

To understand recursion try to draw a tree of the calls and the parameters:

```
factorial(4)  = 4 * factorial(4-1)
                                        |
                                3 * factorial(3-1)
                                               |
                                       2 * factorial(2-1)
                                                      |
                                                      1
```

Try it with the recursive fibonacci formula.

Answer (score 1):

The word 'return' does, indeed, break from the current method and return a value/result. However, you have an 'expression' in the return 'statement' that needs to be evaluated before 'return' can exit.

For example, return 1 + 1; needs to evaluate the operation '+' before it returns.
When you call return func(arguments); java has to call that function before it returns. In this case, it recursively goes through this "call stack" (function calls are put on a 'stack' where the last one in is the first evaluated).

So, to really describe what is going on here:

1) return statement recognizes an expression

2) the expression calls a function on the **stack**

3) the function on the stack hits another return with another function to evaluate

4) ...

5) the "base case" is reached, where a '1' is found.

6) the function calls are executed down the stack to evaluate the expression

Answer (score 1):

Your recursive method can end in only two ways. Either `value` is 1 and it returns 1, or it calls itself with a smaller `value-1` and returns the product of whatever that result was and the current `value`.

The method could have been written more expanded like this:

```
private static int factorial(int value){
    if (value == 1){
        return 1;
    }
    int a = factorial(value - 1);
    return a * value;
}
```

From a stack point of view it looks like this. I've inserted fictitious variables `a`, `b` and `c` to indicate the value of the recursive calls as they return.

```
factorial(4)
  |-- a = factorial(4-1=3)
  |    |-- b = factorial(3-1=2)
  |    |    |-- c = factorial(2-1=1)
  |    |    |    +-- return 1          // <-- deepest point in the stack
  |    |    +-- return c * 2 = 2
  |    +-- return b * 3 = 6
  +-- return a * 4 = 24
```

If you put a larger starting number, the stack would just get deeper, repeatedly calling `factorial(value-1)` until it finally got to `1` and then the stack unwinds to reveal the answer. If you put **much** **much** larger number, you will end up with a *stack overflow* (the namesake of this site!) because you'd run out of memory to hold all of the variables needed.

Answer (score 0):

Java uses the stack to store information between recursive calls. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack for more info.

Answer (score 0):

As I thought, return f(); means execute f() and return the result of f().In recursion , return result; is just a program statement runs after recursion function f(). So it's execution order is contrary to modulated recursion function.