# How do I print the factorials of 0-30 on a table

Tags: java, recursion

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int n = factorial(30);
    int x = 0;
    while (x <= 30) {
        System.out.println(x + " " + n);
        x = x + 1;
    }


    public static int factorial (int n) {   
       if (n == 0) {
             return 1;
        } else {
            return n * factorial (n-1);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to print out something like this:

```
0 1
1 1
2 2
3 6
4 24
...etc, up to 30 (30!)
```

What I'm getting instead is this:

```
0 (30!)
1 (30!)
...etc, up to 30
```

In words, I'm able to create the left column from 0 to 30 but I want to make it print the factorial of the numbers in the right hand column. With my code, it only prints the factorial of 30 in the right-hand column. I want it to print the factorials in order next to their corresponding number. How can I fix my code to do this?

Comment: Why not change `n` inside of your while loop and before printing its value?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recursion and the Return Keyword](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29903226/recursion-and-the-return-keyword)

Comment: SO is not the appropriate forum for homework.

Comment: @AndyJones But it is the place for people with specific, answerable programming questions -- which this is. It's not a duplicate of another question because it came from the same source.

Comment: @AndyJones it's not wrong asking questions from solving homework exercises. What's wrong is asking for solving the homework, but this isn't the case.

Comment: I did most of it myself I'm just having a small problem with a piece of it. By the way  @QPaysTaxes thank you for the help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is pretty simple. Instead of defining a variable, you call the method with the updated `x` every time:

```
System.out.println(x + " " + factorial(x));
```

Note that your loop could be rewritten as a `for` loop, which is exactly what they're designed for:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 30; x++) {
    System.out.println(x + " " + factorial(x));
}
```

Note a couple of things:

1. The `x++`. It's basically a short form of `x = x + 1`, though there are some caveats. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371118/how-do-the-post-increment-i-and-pre-increment-i-operators-work-in-java) for more information about that.
2. `x` is defined *in* the loop (`for (int x = ...`) not before it
3. `n` is never defined or used. Rather than setting a variable that's only used once, I directly used the result of `factorial(x)`.

Note: I'm actually pretty certain that an `int` will overflow when confronted with **30!**. 265252859812191058636308480000000 is a pretty big number. It also overflows `long`, as it turns out. If you want to handle it properly, use [`BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html):

```
public BigInteger factorial(int n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return BigInteger.ONE;
    } else {
        return new BigInteger(n) * factorial(n - 1);
    }
}
```

Because of [`BigInteger#toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#toString())'s magic, you don't have to change anything in `main` to make this work, though I still recommend following the advice above.

Answer (score 0):

As @QPaysTaxes [explains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29906839/2617068), the issue in your code was due to computing the final value and then printing it repeatedly rather than printing each step.

However, even that [working approach](http://ideone.com/8wUfbM) suffers from a lack of efficiency - the result for 1 computes the results for 0 and 1, the result for 2 computes the results for 0, 1, and 2, the result for 3 computes the results for 0, 1, 2, and 3, and so on. Instead, [print each step within the function itself](http://ideone.com/qjabIZ):

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Main
{

    public static BigInteger factorial (int n) {   
        if (n == 0) {
            System.out.println("0 1");
            return BigInteger.ONE;
          } else {
            BigInteger x = BigInteger.valueOf(n).multiply(factorial(n - 1));
          System.out.println(n + " " + x);
            return x;
          }
      }
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    factorial(30);
  }
}
```

Of course, it would be faster and simpler to just [multiply in the loop](http://ideone.com/AvJsSa):

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Main
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    System.out.println("0 1");
    BigInteger y = BigInteger.ONE;
    for (int x = 1; x < 30; ++x) {
        y = y.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(x));
        System.out.println(x + " " + y);
    }
  }
}
```

Just for fun, here's the efficient recursive solution in Python:

```
def f(n):
    if not n:
        print(0, 1)
        return 1
    else:
        a = n*f(n-1)
        print(n, a)
        return a

_ = f(30)
```

And, better still, the iterative solution in Python:

```
r = 1
for i in range(31):
    r *= i or 1
    print(i, r)
```